# How to force a compile error when virtual method hiding of base class occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings, overriding

I have a virtual method in a base class which has a full implementation. A developer deriving from this class might mistakenly create a method with the same name without overriding the base class (not knowing there's a proper base class method to be used). The compiler gives a warning that the new method is hiding the base method.

The problem is compiler warnings are easily ignored or not noticed. Is there a way to give a compiler error instead.. or some kind at your face warning? I want developers to consciously override the base method if they want to use their own implementation and not just create one with same name. I can't force other developers' Visual Studio to set warnings as errors. Plus there are already existing warnings which no one is going to fix.

Side question: If current VS2013 and C#5 has nothing to address this, does VS 2015 or C#6 add anything which helps in this issue?

Comment: No, if developers ignore warnings, then that's their own fault, and there's nothing you can do about it. In terms of "warnings which no-one is going to fix" you could explicitly disable those warnings, either for the project or in those specific places. Basically, you'll need to fix the "warning blindness".

Comment: If they're not going to comply with team rules, then you're probably better finding a new developers in your team. Set a retrospective and tell ask everyone if it's okay not to ignore warnings as a team.

Comment: @lll Developers come and go specially contractors. There are no rules, it's an old app with old warnings and if existing warnings do not break anything, then it's an "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" mentality and attitude. I understand what you're saying but this is not the real world everywhere.

Comment: "I can't force other developers' Visual Studio to set warnings as errors" - then use continuous integration server and turn this setting on in its config. Another option is to fire them all. :)

Comment: I am looking for a technical solution. Not a people solution.

Comment: I agree that there isn't any silver bullet solution for this; but if you perform Code Reviews, then this is a good place to spot and have the erroneous approach corrected.

Comment: Hate to break it to you but the problem you're describing requires a people solution. Any "technical solution" will only be resolved by changing the rules, which is a people solution considering they can change it back. The only way I've solved this issue in the past is by increasing the odds of good code being a copy/paste candidate by going in and correcting a majority of the same copied mistake, or by doing something evil like making a method call implicit (like inside base ctor) and letting side effects from the code running twice cause runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change your project properties to treat a specific warning as error.

> Go to Project Properties -> Build

There Check Specific warnings: under "Treat warnings as erros' and specify:**[0114](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04xcc4t1(v=vs.90).aspx)** as warning number.

[image]

Now this particular warning will appear as error. This could be helpful but it mainly depends on the developers, if they choose to ignore the warning in first place then they can *accidentally* remove this warning number from build properties as well.

For your question:

> does VS 2015 or C#6 add anything which helps in this issue?

You will get the same behaviour/warning in Visual Studio 2015, for C# 6.0. It is same as previous version.

Comment: +1 for providing an actual answer rather than telling the OP to fire their team. Sometimes you have a situation where you inherit a legacy project and it builds with a bunch of warnings, and you can't just go and fix them all but you want to make sure that you don't introduce certain new issues.

Comment: If OP is going to turn the warnings into compilation errors, isn't he going to have to fix them all anyway, which could have solved his problem in the first place?

Comment: @moarboilerplate, this is not turning *all the warnings* to errors, instead it is specifically turning warning for hiding member to errors. So OP can ignore the others.

Comment: @Habib I wasn't suggesting this was going to make all warnings errors, I was addressing Erik's point by saying that if the project won't build until OP fixes all of the 0114 errors, he has to go and fix all of them, which might have been all he needed to do in the first place

Comment: @moarboilerplate, my bad..Read your comment in the context of my post :)

Comment: @moarboilerplate Yeah, but this is one of the warnings are less common to see but more potentially severe than average if left unnoticed. Now that the OP knows how to enable errors for this one warning, he can see how many errors are generated and can make a decision how to move forward with them. That's a lot more helpful than telling him to fire his whole team!

Comment: @Erik True, it depends why it's happening in the first place. My assumption is that it's because a class already in the codebase does it and it's being copied and pasted, which would be mitigated by OP fixing all the errors. If that's not the case, and people are writing classes from scratch problematically, then yeah, something like this is probably necessary.